# unknown while while statement

Tags: c#, .net

I see some code of some guy that goes like this:

```
while (!(baseType == typeof(Object)))
{
    ....
    baseType = baseType.BaseType;
    if (baseType != null)
        continue;
    break;
} while (baseType != typeof(Object));
```

What is `while(...) {...} while(...)` statement?
is the following equivalent code?

```
while (baseType != null && baseType != typeof(Object))
{
    ....
    baseType = baseType.BaseType;
}
```

Comment: maybe second loop should be commented just to show that `}` is the end of the loop. :)

Comment: Not quite, the loop can be entered with baseType == null.  But hard to believe you didn't improve it.  Good luck, you'll be in for some more rude surprises I imagine.

Comment: Is this how the code actually exists in the code?  Thebreak statement is always going to happen, even after the continue statement, which hardly makes any sense.

Comment: @Ramhound: after the continue statement the code at the while statement is executed (i.e. the condition will be checked again). The break statement is NOT executed after continue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `while() ... while();` statement, <strike>so it's really two while statements, like:</strike>

When they have the same condition, like in your example, the second one is useless.

#### Edit:

Actually, doing some testing I came to realise that it's actually two loops, like:

```
while(...) { ... }
while(...);
```

Comment: There is no “statement while(cond)” loop in C#. There is “_do_ statement while(cond)”. The example is two loops one _after_ another, not one nested inside the other.

Comment: @Mormegil: Yes, I came to the same conclusion.

Comment: -1: Both while statements are on the same level. There is no inner or outer while.

Comment: @Naor: It works fine. You shouldn't even need the null check as all types inherit `object`.

Comment: @Guffa: the null check still makes a difference. We don't know what baseType is originally assigned and what BaseType returns. The original loop breaked on null, therefore having the null check is not the same.

Comment: @slfan: That's certainly a point. Then the null check would be better off in an `if` statement around it rather than in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You have two while statements in a row. The 2nd could end up as an endless loop, because the first runs until the first condition is true or baseType becomes null.
Then the 2nd loop starts:

```
while (baseType != typeof(Object));
```

If baseType is not changed by another thread, the loop won't terminate. Because the first loop checks the same condition, the 2nd is never run, except when baseType is null.

Your code is not exactly the same, because the first code breaks the loop if baseType is null and then ends in the endless loop. I would prefer your code, it's a lot clearer. Try to avoid continue and break.

Comment: I don't know if this code block (where the whiles statements are) executed, but I know that the code executed and done.

Comment: on a side note: I have seen similar constructs in code for embedded systems where this was deemed "THE way" to handle error conditions, because when you stopped the program in the debugger you would end up in that second while